# ol li text alignment issue with form-group in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a form which have numbers of each `form-group`. I am getting alignment problem if the text is long. Can you please look into the issue http://jsfiddle.net/rvytrwqk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `vertical-align` to your `label`s:

```
.wrapper label { vertical-align: top; }
```

Bootstrap styling makes the `label`s inside `form-group`s as `inline-block` and hence, you would need to add the alignment for your use-case. `inline-block`s are are baseline aligned by default.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/rvytrwqk/7/**

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to overwrite bootstrap's css to below. http://jsfiddle.net/rvytrwqk/2/

```
.wrapper label {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvytrwqk/4/)  Just need to add CSS for display:block in lable..`display:block;`

Answer (score 0):

Check this out..

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}
.wrapper label {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Phone</label>
        <input class="form-control input-small" type="text">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input class="form-control input-small" type="text">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Write a review - Share your experience with u</label>
        <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
      </div>
    </li>
    <ol>
</div>
```